# Problem with jQuery draggable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-draggable

I am developing map like functionality, check http://jsfiddle.net/JxjeL/4/. I am using jQuery draggable plugin for dragging of image like a map. Normally it works, but if I take cursor outside the page while dragging, image get stuck.

To reproduce:

1. Drag upwards.
2. Then downwards.
3. While dragging downwards, take the mouse pointer outside the body/page.
4. Release the mouse
5. Bring back mouse pointer within image
6. Now try dragging downwards.

You will not able to drag down, it will get stuck at a random position.

I also captured the window resize event and resetting 'containment' according to changed size.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by removing overflow:hidden from body and moving to image container. Check updated jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/JxjeL/6/

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to the iframe JSFiddle uses.

I'm trying to reproduce the bug using the demo page for draggable: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

By copying the exact same code into JSFiddle I can reproduce the same problem in that frame, but on the actual demo page I cannot.

Not sure if that's any help though if you really need to use it in an iframe.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on a actual demo page also, by moving the cursor outside browser.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I didn't try hard enough :( I tried doing that in a smaller window in Chrome. What browser did you reproduce the error with?

Comment: near about every browser has this issue.